# Como recoger json de webservices en swift

Tags: json, ios, swift, xcode

Mi web services me entrega la siguiente información en formato json:

```
{"login":true,"datauser":"iduser":"1","docuser":"111111111","nameuser":"DIEGO","idperfil":"1"}}
```

Como recojo esta información en un array en swift mediante JSONSerialization.

Estoy intentando mediante `String: Any`, pero de esta manera no puedo tratar la información de forma ordenada.

Mi codigo json es:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){data, response,
        error in guard let data = data else {
        print("Error \(String(describing: error))")
        return
        }
        do {
            print("Recibimos respuesta")
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(json)
                }
            }
        } catch  _{
            print("Error de parseo \(String(describing: error))")
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("respuesta: \(String(describing: responseString))")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Mis errores son los siguientes:

```
Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes pasar el JSON directamente a una clase o estructura con el protocolo `Codable`. Quedaría así:

```
struct TuStruct: Codable { //Agregas el protocolo Codable
    var login: Bool
    var datauser: String 
    var iduser: String
    var docuser: String
    var nameuser: String
    var idperfil: String 

init(login: Bool, datauser: String, iduser: String, docuser: String, nameuser: String, idperfil: String) {
    self.login = login 
    self.datauser = datauser
    self.iduser = iduser
    self.docuser = docuser
    self.nameuser = nameuser
    self.idperfil = idperfil
    }
}
```

En el código que tienes sería:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){data, response,
        error in guard let data = data else {
        print("Error \(String(describing: error))")
        return
        }
        do {
            print("Recibimos respuesta")
            let decoder = JSONDecoder() //Agregamos una variable de tipo JSONDecoder
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let json = try decoder.decode(TuStruct.self, from: data)//Decodificamos la data de tipo JSON en la estructura Decodable
                    print(json)
                }
        } catch  _{
            print("Error de parseo \(String(describing: error))")
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("respuesta: \(String(describing: responseString))")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por compartir tus conocimientos