# Pasar detalles de un objecto a otra View a través de un tableView

Tags: swift, objeto, uitableview

Soy un poco novato con Swift y se me presenta la siguiente duda:

Hago una consulta a una bbdd y obtengo una serie de pedidos (código, nombre, fecha, destino...) y los muestro sobre una tabla el código y el nombre sin problemas.

Ahora bien, quiero que al pinchar sobre una fila de la tabla de pedidos, vaya a otra ventana donde se amplía la información de ese pedido y muestre todos los datos (código, nombre, fecha, destinatario, dirección, país, observaciones, etc...).

Esto último también lo hago bien, pero tengo que crear un array dato por dato y luego pasar array por array con un segue hacia la siguiente View. Esto funciona bien, pero creo que habría alguna manera más eficiente de hacer este traspaso de información, tipo   pasar un objeto o algo así, pero no consigo hacerlo.

Este es parte de mi código, que sospecho podría ser mucho más eficiente:

```
    class ViewVerPedidos: UIViewController{
               
        var dateOrders = [String]()
        var originOrders = [String]()
        var destinationOrders = [String]()
        var statusOrders = [String]()
    
        var codeOrders = [String]()
        var clienteOrders = [String]()
        var bultosOrders = [Int]()
        var observationsOrders = [String]()
        
        var origenName = [String]()
        var origenAddress = [String]()
        var origenCp = [String]()
        var origenLocalidad = [String]()
        var origenProvincia = [String]()
        var origenPhone = [String]()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            tableOrders.dataSource = self
            tableOrders.delegate = self
            
            // Acceso a la celda personalizada
            tableOrders.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCellOrders", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableviewCellOrders")
            
            obtOrders()
            
        }
        
        func obtOrders(){
            NetworkingProvider.shared.getAllOrders() { (pedidos) in
                
                self.codeOrders.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.codigo))
                self.clienteOrders.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.nombre))
                self.bultosOrders.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.bultos))
                self.observationsOrders.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.observaciones))
                self.dateOrders.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.fecha))
                self.originOrders.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.origen))
                self.statusOrders.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.cod_estado))
                
                self.origenName.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.origen))
                self.origenAddress.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.rec_domicilio))
                self.origenCp.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.rec_codigopostal))
                self.origenLocalidad.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.rec_localidad))
                self.origenProvincia.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.rec_provincia))
                self.origenPhone.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.rec_telefono1))
                
               
                 DispatchQueue.main.async{ [weak self] in
                    self?.tableOrders.reloadData()
                }
                
            } failure: { (error) in
                print(error.debugDescription)
                return
            }
        }
        
            }
    
    
extension ViewVerPedidos: UITableViewDataSource{
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return dateOrders.count
        }
        
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                
            let cell = tableOrders.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableviewCellOrders", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCellOrders
            cell?.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
            cell!.lblCodeOrders.text = codeOrders[indexPath.row]
            cell!.lblDestinationOrders.text = destinationOrders[indexPath.row]            
            return cell!
        }
    }
    
    extension ViewVerPedidos: UITableViewDelegate{
            
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "cell2", sender: indexPath.row)
        }
        
        // Envío de parámetros a través del Segue
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "cell2"{
                if let destination = segue.destination as? ViewDatosPedido{
            
                    let selectedRow = sender! as! Int
                    
                    destination.estado = statusOrders[selectedRow]
                    destination.codigo = codeOrders[selectedRow]
                    destination.fecha = dateOrders[selectedRow]
                    destination.origin = originOrders[selectedRow]
                    destination.destination = destinationOrders[selectedRow]
                    destination.cliente = clienteOrders[selectedRow]
                    destination.bultos = bultosOrders[selectedRow]
                    destination.observations = observationsOrders[selectedRow]
                    destination.originName = originName[selectedRow]
                    destination.originAddress = originAddress[selectedRow]
                    destination.originCp = originCp[selectedRow]
                    destination.originLocalidad = originLocalidad[selectedRow]
                    destination.originProvincia = originProvincia[selectedRow]
                    destination.originPhone = originPhone[selectedRow]

                }
            }
            }
        
   }
```

Ya digo que este código funciona perfectamente, pero sospecho que no es todo lo eficiente que debería ser.

Mi intención es pasar directamente un objeto con los datos de ese pedido en concreto. Algo así como: destination.Pedido = pedido[selectedRow] pero por más vueltas que le doy no consigo ver cómo se haría algo así.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Los datos los obtienes de una bdd local o de una api rest?

Comment: En una API rest

Comment: Te recomendaría enviar la respuesta de la api como json y usar una estructura `Codable` en Swift para almacenar esa respuesta, así te evitas de hacer n recorridos a los array. Mi respuesta acá te puede servir a pasar el json a la estructura. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371318/como-recoger-json-de-webservices-en-swift/371402#371402

Comment: Si no me equivoco podrías usar `try decoder.decode([TuStruct.self], from: data)` para almacenar directamente un array.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Efectivamente ahí estaba la solución: crear un objeto Pedido (por ejemplo) e instanciarlo a través de un constructor, que era la parte que me faltaba por crear. De esta manera el código es mucho más limpio. Mil gracias por el consejo!